# return@method_name in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, annotations, higher-order-functions

I am learning one project for RxJAVA in that there is one method. In which, I think, the creator had passed lambda.

```
private fun doSomeWork() {
    getObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())                                                                           
            .map { apiUsers ->
                return@map Utils.convertApiUserListToUserList(apiUsers)
            }
            .subscribe(getObserver())
}
```

In this code, I am getting confusion with `return@map` statement. because generally, I am using return without any annotations. When I removed that annotations it showed an error that "this return statement does not allow here".

My main question is: **what is the aim to use `return@method_name`?**

I have tried myself to find it out but I did not get a satisfactory answer about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly return inside a lambda. The return value is the result of the last statement inside the block. So you can remove `return@map`. You cannot simply say `return` because that would imply to return from the external function (`doSomeWork()`), that it is not allowed in this scenario

Comment: May help: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression

Comment: Thanks. So, maybe that is mentioned there just for better understanding. If that is not mentioned there still code works as usual.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. I think these comments solve my confusion.